# how to combine two meshes without ugly overlapping?

Tags: modifiers

I tried a few things but didn`t get it working. how to combine two meshes without ugly overlapping?
[image]

Comment: You could use a shrinkwrap modifier to place the fabric over the armor. You may have to get rid of some of  your mesh, not sure of your exact setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use a Boolean modifier, then relax the edges of the cut where the meshes join until they are smooth and clean looking.

Comment: what do you mean by "then relax".
I tried boolean already but the result will be the same as in the image.

Comment: Select all the vertices of the edge, in edit mode, then go to the vertex menu at the top, then select the smooth vertices function, there will be an option menu that pops up like when you add an object. I think that will help smooth out the ugly overlap.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the white armour should be over the black fabric/plastic. So I would shrink down the black shoulder part until the white is on top of it.

You could also  boolean it and then try to smooth it out in sculpting mode but boolean will leave a messy topology with a lot of N-Gons that will not be sculptable very predictably.

Answer (score 0):

1. click inside mesh (smaller mesh)
2. boolean: difference and select object: outside mesh (bigger mesh)
   result: ok